# Why operator= is not working for standard types with template placement new?

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading

So ~T() works even for standard types (which are not classes/structs) I assumed `operator=(const T &)` also can be valid as the default method, but it's not:

```
#include <new>

template <class T> void foo(T el) {
  alignas(T) unsigned char buf[sizeof(T)];
  T *ptr = new (buf) T(el);
  // error: request for member 'operator=' in '* ptr', which is of non-class type 'int'
  // ptr->operator=(42);
  ptr->~T();
}

int main() { foo(42); }
```

Is ~T() synthetic construction to standard types for compatibility?

Comment: I find it vastly frustrating that primitives don't have the various operators as members.  It' means I can't have a template iterator wrapper that delegates to `base.operator->()` :(

Comment: Why would anyone want to write `ptr->operator=(42)` instead of `*ptr = 42`?

Comment: Agreed. Just use `*ptr = 42;` and let the compiler sort it out for you.  You really should not explicitly call operators by name when you can avoid it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., my example aims to show the ability to call something borrowed from user-defined type (destructor, which is the default method) by a simple type and expect success explicitly calling another default method (copy assignment operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The standard defines "pseudo-destructor calls", so that something like `ptr->~T()` or `ref.~T()` is valid for built-in scalar types (§[expr.prim.id.dtor]):

> 1. An *id-expression* that denotes the destructor of a type `T` names the destructor of `T` if `T` is a class type (11.4.6), otherwise the *id-expression* is said to name a *pseudo-destructor*.
> 2. If the *id-expression* names a pseudo-destructor, `T` shall be a scalar type and the *id-expression* shall appear as the right operand of a class member access (7.6.1.4) that forms the *postfix-expression* of a function call (7.6.1.2). [*Note:* Such a call has no effect. —*end note*]

For better or worse, the same thing is not done for other operators that are valid on built-in scalar types, so (as you've found) you can't refer to `some_int.operator=`, for example).

There has been (considerable) discussion of some sort of uniform function call syntax, that would allow the compiler to sort out at least some things like this, but although it's been proposed at least a couple of times (early on by Francis Glassborrow, more recently by Bjarne and Herb Sutter), it hasn't been accepted. If you're interested in this apart from using it in C++, D does support something on this order you might find interesting to look into.

Outside of that, although it's not as easy as you'd probably like, you can *probably* use SFINAE to select between `foo = bar;` and `foo.operator=(bar);`, if you really need to do so (though I'll admit, I'm not sure what advantage you get from the `.operator=` syntax).